# `this` and `new` with generator

Tags: javascript, generator

Is this well defined? I.e. I have a generator `function* gen()` and I'm doing `new gen()`. Do I get the iterator back or the new object, or both merged together? And inside the function, does `this` points as usual to the new object?

I tried this:

```
function* gen() {
    this.f = "hey";
    yield this;
    return 42;
}
var x = new gen();
console.log("x:", x, x.toString());
var n1 = x.next();
console.log("1:", n1);
var n2 = x.next();
console.log("2:", n2);
console.log("x:", x, x.toString());
console.log("eq:", n1.value === x);
```

And the output is:

```
x: {} [object Generator]
1: { value: { f: 'hey' }, done: false }
2: { value: 42, done: true }
x: { f: 'hey' } [object Generator]
eq: true
```

So apparently, `x` is both the iterator and the new object. The new object is returned immediately, although it is not filled yet.

Is all this the expected and well-defined behaviour?

Does it make sense to use a generator as a constructor (e.g. in async code)?